# Connecting 2 LANs via Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, wireless-bridge, wireless-access-point, bridge-router

At my home I have a LAN with very fast internet (120Mbit/s). On my roof I installed a Wi-Fi access point to get good Wi-Fi around my house. About 200meters (600feet) from me a friend lives and I want to give him access to my LAN. He also has a LAN with printers, media players, etc.

How would I connect his LAN to mine?

I have done a test. I have a spare Wi-Fi router which I can configure for Client Mode and also Bridge Mode.

In Bridge Mode I managed to configure it to connect to my access point. The laptop connected to the spare Wi-Fi router nicely, got an IP address from my LAN, and an internet connection was possible but was extremely slow. Took about 1 minute to just open the Google search page.

In Client Mode I could not get anything.

My question is, is Bridge Mode the way to go? Did I maybe misconfigure something?
Or should I try harder to get Client Mode working?

My Wi-Fi access point is simply in AP mode. Is there some other setting that would be better to use for a Point to Point connection? 
If I can't use my own Wi-Fi access point that's no problem.

Comment: You have 600 foot range of WiFi, why does he not just access your wifi like you would?

Comment: Do both WiFi devices support WDS? If not, why not use routing rather than bridging?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your friend could consider a high gain aerial, particularly a focused aerial (tube) or a powerful WAGI type. This could easily provide the required signal strength at a range of 600'. You might need to choose the channel carefully though!